# Does initializing a variable with true or false establish the direction of the content in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, animation, if-statement

```
   <script>
     var switchDirection = false;
      function doAnimation() {
        var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
           var currentLeft = divAdvert.offsetLeft;
            var newLocation;
           if (!switchDirection) {
               newLocation = currentLeft + 2;
               if (currentLeft >= 400) {
              switchDirection = true;
              }
          } else {
                  newLocation = currentLeft - 2;
                  if (currentLeft <= 0) {
                  switchDirection = false;
                  }
          }
             divAdvert.style.left = newLocation + "px";
       }
     setInterval(doAnimation, 10);
   </script>
```

I want to know why a new variable with the value of false has been declared in the beginning of the function.

Comment: …to be toggled in the function later apparently? Please tell us what parts of the function you did not understand.

Comment: var switchDirection = false; This variable keeps track of the direction in which the content is currently going. If switchDirection is false, the content is moving from left to right, which is the default. If switchDirection is true, the content is moving from right to left. // This is what the author of the program writes in the explanation of the code.I do not understand this point that how initializing the variable to false makes the direction of the content go from left to right. –

Comment: It's not the initialisation of the variable that makes the div do anything. It's the `doAnimation` function which uses the `switchDirection` state to control in which direction the content is moved in the current step.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing like this. May be developer using this variable later in page as this is global variable. He is calling function from setInterval hence its going to called repeatedly. So, he is keeping that value in some global variable as it will be lost if kept inside function.
Name is like that just to know what was the intention of variable.Its simple variable.

This line is changing the location :-
    divAdvert.style.left = newLocation + "px";

When switchDirection is false , auther is adding value:-

```
if (!switchDirection) {
           newLocation = currentLeft + 2;
```

Once it is more that 400 , author changing the variable value

```
  if (currentLeft >= 400) {
          switchDirection = true;

         }
```

Then he is moving it in other direction and again vice versa,

```
     newLocation = currentLeft - 2;
              if (currentLeft <= 0) {
              switchDirection = false;
              }
```

Instead of giving value true false , s/he could have used values left and right or ltr and rtl but as he has only 2 values, he used true and false.

Its simple variable , you can give any name like dir or xyz it will work in same way.
And if you change all the false with true and true with false code will work same.

Comment: var switchDirection = false;
This variable keeps track of the direction in which the content is currently going. If
switchDirection is false, the content is moving from left to right, which is the
default. If switchDirection is true, the content is moving from right to left.
//
This is what the author of the program writes in the explanation of the code.I do not understand this point that how initializing the variable to false makes the direction of the content go from left to right.